# Probability of miss detection and probability of false alarm in frame synchronization

Tags: digital-communications, synchronization

I'm working on frame synchronization, and I don't fully understand the probability of miss detection and probability of false alarm in evaluating the performance of the synchronization block. As far as I understand:

1. Probability of false alarm is the probability when the correlation peak is greater than the threshold, but there isn't actually a signal present or there's a signal but the peak happens in the wrong position.
2. Probability of miss detection is the probability when there is a signal but the correlation peak is less than the threshold

Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Sounds good to me.